# Is there a way to enable a reload on save feature in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: reactjs, macos, visual-studio, hot-reload

I've been searching for over an hour now, trying to find if there's a way to have Visual Studio reload my React web application on save. Currently I have to restart the run every time I want to see changes. Store extensions won't work with the Mac version.

Comment: What are you using to run your react application, create-react-app? Reloading on save is usually a feature of the development server and not the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me when I first used CRA. Solved it by using a .env folder in the root of my project containing:

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

And in the package.json file I changed the "start" script.

```
"start": "FAST_REFRESH=false react-scripts start",
```

That would solve that for your project, but what solved my issue with all my projects was installing CRA globally.